# Mapping Cartesian function onto polar plane and finding the Length of that mapped function?

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, polar-coordinates, arc-length

The problem involves: mapping a Cartesian function (with domain $0$ - $2\pi$) onto the polar plane.This transformation maps the value of the Cartesian function for every angle around the center point.

E.g $f(x) = 1$ would map the unit circle

$g(x) = x$ would map a spiral

The problem is to find a generalized method of finding the length of the mapped 'curves'

For the general Cartesian function $f(x)$, its length from $a$ to $b$ is $L= \int_a^b \sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}$.

Update: Answer found for 'curved' length $L= \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{f(x)^2+f'(x)^2}$.   I am not excactly sure why this works but arrived to this conclusion by trial and error

Comment: $f(x) = 1$ can be written just as easily as $r(\theta) = 1$. Likewise, $g(x) = x$ turns into $r(\theta) = \theta$. These would graph a circle of radius $1$ and a spiral, respectively.

Comment: If you're trying to make a straight line on a polar graph, that is to say, graph $f(x) = 1$ on the polar plane, then use these rules: $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$, $x=r\cos\theta$, $y = r\sin\theta$, $\theta = \tan^{-1} \frac{y}x$.

Comment: Then we'd get: $y=1$ --> $r\sin\theta = 1$ --> $r(\theta) = \frac1{\sin\theta}$ --> $r = \csc\theta$.

Comment: I am looking for a formula for the length of the polar function in terms of the Cartesian function